# Compare the MOSFET and LDMOSFET

Tags: transistors

My major is not electronic, but I really really need the answer of this question:

Compare the MOSFET and LDMOSFET.

Since my major is not electronic, I have searched what is MOSFET and what is LDMOSFET but I didn't know which aspect of them to compare. Could you give me some answer? The answer shouldn't be too long (less than 15 lines). I'm not lazy but they don't require a very detail answer.

Comment: This question shows no attempt at a solution and should be closed.

Comment: Hi Leon Heller. Thank you for your comment and I'm really sorry if my question annoys you. I understand this situation because sometimes I read some easy/nonsense/stupid question in these forum and I also though the asker didn't try to solve his problem at all. For my case, maybe the question I ask is very easy, but I don't have any knowledge in electronic. I did try to search but I couldn't find the solution. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

A [MOSFET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET) is a metal–oxide–semiconductor field-effect transistor used for switching and amplification.

An [LDMOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDMOS) FET is a laterally diffused metal oxide semiconductor. They are typically used in power amplifiers for radio and microwave frequencies.

From the Wikipedia page:

> Silicon-based LDMOS FETs are widely used in RF power amplifiers for base-stations as the requirement is for high output power with a corresponding drain to source breakdown voltage usually above 60 volts.

If you need more specific information, you'll have to compare a particular MOSFET to a particular LDMOS FET.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness. Honestly I have the general examination this week. It's called general because the questions include all majors (electronic, telecommunication, network, signal processing) in my department. This is one of the question they gave me in advance and it might appear in the exam. I have about 10 minutes to write the answer. The questions are given by professors in department and I don't think it can be changed. So could you give me some comparison in general about these two semiconductors. Thank you again.